# angular reading a file from file input via readAsDataURL does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following code.

`directive`

```
.directive('area', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();

            fileReader.onload = function (e) {
                scope.image = e.target.result;
                scope.$apply();
            }

            el.on('change', function () {
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(el[0].files[0]);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

`controller`

```
.controller('areaController',
    ['$scope', 
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.image = "";
        }
    ]
);
```

Somehow when I add a image to file input then I get following error

`areaDirective.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should modify it to

```
el.on('change', function (e) {
 var files = (e.srcElement || e.target).files
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
 });
```